Datetime index not converting correctly to datetimeindex
I have a csv file with data and a datetime stamp, and I am trying to correctly format the datetime so that I can resample the data.
I have a csv that I have imported of the format:
                           DryBulbTemperature
LocalTime                                    
2023-01-01 00:00:00-07:00                -4.0
2023-01-01 01:00:00-07:00                -2.0
2023-01-01 02:00:00-07:00                -4.0
2023-01-01 03:00:00-07:00                -4.0
2023-01-01 04:00:00-07:00                -6.0

[9995 rows x 1 columns]

I have already run:
data['LocalTime'] = pd.to_datetime(data['LocalTime'])
data.set_index('LocalTime', inplace=True)
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index)

(intentionally redundant, just to check)
and confirmed that the values in the index are timestamps
data.index[999] Timestamp('2023-02-06 00:00:00-0700', tz='UTC-07:00')
But then later when trying to resample:
data['DryBulbTemperature'].resample('D').mean()
I get this error:
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'
I've been through several other posts and example, and is seems like this should work, so any help is appreciated.

which pandas version are you using? could you try the same but set the intex to UTC datetime (pd.to_datetime(data['LocalTime'], utc=True))?

provide print(data.info()) and print(data.head().to_dict())

pandas version is 2.2.1.  And that utc=True did it!  Looking at the documentation again I see why now.

glad you got that solved; I'm still a bit confused about the error message you got; I couldn't reproduce that with the data shown.
